# Embedding Onedrive file picker in an iframe

Tags: onedrive

Want to embed the onedrive filepicker in an iframe
https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v72/js-picker-open.htm

MSFT says that it can be done only by trusted partners. Anyone knows how to become one
or
Any alternate way to achieve this?